# Setting Checked On NodeCheck Event

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, treeview, ms-access-2003

Setting the checked property during the `NodeCheck` event has been causing it to revert to its previous state.

For example:The node is checked, and the event below gets fired. It finds that the node is checked and sets it to be false. If I walk through the code with a break, the node will reflect this in the user interface. Although, as soon as the code hits the end sub, the checkbox will jump back to being set to true.

```
Private Sub treeviewExample_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As Object)
     If Node.Checked = True Then
            Node.Checked = False
     ElseIf Node.Checked = False Then
            Node.Checked = True
     End If
end sub
```

How do I set the checked property during the `NodeCheck` event?

I have tried the solution [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/treeview-resetting-node-checkbox-vba-code-t3067739.html) that sets the node to a local or global variable and then sets it, and it does the same thing.

Comment: The NodeCheck event is fired because the value of Checked has changed for the node. Windows checks / clears the check for you. You do not have to change the value in code unless you want to change the checked value in response to the user doing something else.

Comment: The way I am using nodes is to verify permissions or not. If the user does not have security to edit permissions then I want the node to reset to its original correct value, rather than showing the user he/she has security to change it.

Comment: Read this please: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the Checkboxes property False and use the Windows API to set the checkboxes property. Then use the NodeClick event to choose whether to check or uncheck the node.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const TVS_CHECKBOXES As Long = &H100
Private Const GWL_STYLE As Long = (-16)
Private Const TVS_HASLINES As Long = 2
Private Const TV_FIRST As Long = &H1100
Private Const TVM_SETBKCOLOR As Long = (TV_FIRST + 29)

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()

    SetTVCheckboxStyle TreeView1

End Sub

Private Sub SetTVCheckboxStyle(pobjTV As TreeView)

    Dim lngCurStyle As Long
    Dim lngResult   As Long

    ' === Set the Checkbox style of the TreeView ===
    ' As advised by Microsoft, due to a bug in the TreeView control,
    ' set the Checkbox style of the TreeView by using the following
    ' API calls, rather than simply setting the "Checkboxes" property
    ' to True ...
    lngCurStyle = GetWindowLong(pobjTV.hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    lngResult = SetWindowLong(pobjTV.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, _
                              lngCurStyle Or TVS_CHECKBOXES)

End Sub
```

As you add your node set some property of the nodes you want disabled so you can check the property later. I chose to use the ForeColor property so the disabled nodes would have a disabled appearance. Then use the NodeClick event to check, clear, or ignore the user clicks.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

    If Node.ForeColor <> vbGrayText Then
        Node.Checked = Not Node.Checked
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still working through if this solution will work for me, but you may want to look into the `GetWindowLongptr` and `SetWindowLongptr` functions instead of `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong`. They seem to have been deprecated and the newer functions support both 32 and 64 bit Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Also an issue I have with this is that the event is also fired on the label. How could I cover for label clicks VS. check box clicks?

Comment: I'm not sure how or if you can discern label from checkbox clicks. Unfortunately because you cannot disable selected nodes this is just a kludge. Another solution is to not use checkboxes at all, but use images that look like a checkbox in it's various states. IMO the ideal solution would be to re-think the UI design.

Comment: Disappointingly I can't make the move on the Treeview, although I do like your imagelist suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue, and discovered a workaround.

You can't set the 'checked-ness' of a treeview's checkbox in its own NodeCheck event.

However, assuming you're capturing the user clicking the checkbox, the Treeview_Click event fires immediately afterwards (as they had to click to change it), and you *can* set checkboxes in that event.

So all you need to do is store a reference to the checkbox you need to be changed and set it in the Click event, before clearing the reference.

```
Private WithEvents tv As TreeView

Private checkBoxToSet_Node As Node
Private checkBoxToSet_value As Boolean


Private Sub tv_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

    Dim prompt As VbMsgBoxResult

    prompt = MsgBox("Do you REALLY want to set this checkbox?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)

    ' can't set the checked-ness here, so we store it

    If (prompt <> vbYes) Then
        Set checkBoxToSet_Node = Node
        checkBoxToSet_value = Not Node.checked
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub tv_Click()

    ' check if we had previously set a node to have its checkbox changed

    If (Not checkBoxToSet_Node Is Nothing) Then
        tv.Nodes(checkBoxToSet_Node.key).checked = checkBoxToSet_value

        Set checkBoxToSet_Node = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```